# adding EventListener in a loop with index as argument at each iteration

Tags: javascript, closures

When creating a table with JavaScript,
I'm trying to set an event listener in a loop.
the event listener in each iteration should call the same function but with the current index as an argument.
I found here that I can use closures with a function array but do I have to use an array? I don't understand why the below code is not working?

```
function createTable(id, headers, keys, data, url) {
var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
var header = table.createTHead();
var tr = header.insertRow(0);
var i, j, td;
var headersLength = headers.length;
for (i = 0; i < headersLength; i++) {
    th = document.createElement('th');
    th.innerText = headers[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    var tbodyId = "t_body";
    var sortFunction = createSortFunction(tbodyId, i);
    th.addEventListener('click', function() {
        sortFunction;
    });
}

function createSortFunction(tbodyId, i) {
    return function() { alert(i); };
}
```

Comment: Anything in the console such as errors? Also, we're not seeing the whole picture. Where is the variable "tr" being declared? Where is the variable headers[] being declared? Why are you showing us createSortFunction?

Perhaps it's as simple as you called the two functions differently. First you say "sortFunction" but the name of the function below is called "createSortFunction"

Comment: Can update the question with relevant HTML?

Comment: @George Daniel No there are no errors in the console. Only that no I don't see the alert when I click on the `th` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `sortFunction` in a function because it is holding a function which you can pass directly to `addEventListener`

```
th.addEventListener('click', sortFunction);
```

Comment: switching `th.addEventListener('click', function() {sortFunction; });` with your answer worked.